# Using sed to replace a line with many special characters?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am writing a rather massive script for a project and one of the issues I am running into before I can complete it is using the sed command.

I am trying to find a line that has (located in cache.php):

```
$cache_directory = './cache';
```

and replace the information in `'./cache'` with a variable named `$new_cache_directory`.

One of the problems I am running into is the `./cache` exists multiple times. I only want to replace that one line, but I also don't want to "hard code" the line number to "future proof" it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i.bak "s:^.*\(\$cache_directory = \)\('./cache'\):\1$new_cache_directory:" infile
```

Comment: This worked with one exception, the $new_cache_directory variable was not passed infile. It shows $cache_directory = '$new_cache_directory';

Comment: @Jason: ok. what is your expected output?

Comment: This is an interactive script so the user is defining $new_cache_directory using printf and read... Basically the variable needs to be passed to the file. So if they answer whackachuck that is what the file shows. Is that a little more descriptive?

Comment: @Jason: answer is updated.removed backslash before `$new_cache_directory`

Comment: I see, so you "unescaped" the $ on the variable correct?

Comment: @Jason: if you don't need the original file as backup then just use `sed -i "s:....`

Comment: Actually, I still need the ./ in front of the $new_cache_directory.. I'm going to try to figure that out really quick..

Comment: @Jason: yes. you are right.

Comment: @Jason: `sed -i.bak "s:^.*\(\$cache_directory = \)\('./cache'\):\1./$new_cache_directory:" infile`

Comment: Thanks, you just beat me to it! Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

So I guess you want to replace 'cache' with the content of said variable, not with its name:

```
sed 's#^$cache_directory = ../cache.;#$cache_directory = '$new_cache_directory'#' script.php
```

So you have different problems to solve: Normally a sed command uses slashes to separate the parts: 's/foo/bar/'. When dealing with paths, this is disturbing, but we can use many delimiters - they are just implicitly declared in following the 's'.

Problem 2 is similar. We often specify the command in single quotes:

```
sed 'command' file
```

But here we have apostrophes around ./cache - what to do? One idea would be, to use

```
sed "command" file
```

instead, which often works, but not here. The apostrophes prevent the Dollar-sign from being interpreted, but quotes wouldn't prevent that. Often, you don't even need apostrophes, and can write:

```
sed s/standart/standard/g sample.txt
```

but again, you have $cache_directory as a variable in the command, which would be interpreted. So I just replace the apostrophes with the joker sign, dot, and would be really surprised, if some other expression would match that part: `../cache.` like `xy/cachei` - not very probable, is it?

But you like $new_cache_directory to be replaced with the content of the variable, so I switch masking off with `= '`, insert the variable, and switch masking on again to finish the command with '#'.

Comment: Thank you for the well explained thought process, I really do appreciate it when people take the time out to throughly explain something. However, that method didn't work. it displayed the output of the file in terminal.

Comment: Well - to generate a file, you usually use `sed 'cmd' file.in > file.out`, but to replace the file, you use `sed -i 'cmd' file`. But the latter works just once, so I thought you would like to keep the source, and know about piping the output somewhere.